# Django save default value in Proxy Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Different proxy models should be different in type.
If I query those models I the right ones.

I am trying to save a default type field in a proxy model. 
I don't want to set it everytime in the view.

This does not work. The type field is always "TYPE1".

models.py:

```python
class MyModel(models.Model):

    class ModelType(models.TextChoices):
        TYPE1 = 'TYPE1', _('TYPE1')
        TYPE2 = 'TYPE2', _('TYPE2')

    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=ModelType.choices, default='TYPE1')


class Type2Manager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(Type2Manager, self).get_queryset().filter(type='TYPE2')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'type': 'TYPE2'})
        return super(Type2Manager, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Type2ProxyModel(MyModel):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    objects = Type2Manager()
```

views.py:

```python
def create_type2_model(request):
    form = Type2Form(request.POST, initial={})
    f = form.save(commit=False) 
    f.save()
```

forms.py:

```python
class Type2Form(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Type2ProxyModel
```

Update 25.02.2020 12:18:

I found out that this sets the correct type. But I don't know how to use create() in a ModelForm.

```python
class Type2Manager(models.Manager):

    ...

    def create(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'type': 'TYPE2'})
        return super(Type2Manager, self).create(**kwargs)
```

```python
Type2ProxyModel.objects.create()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A model manager operates on a "table-level". When you create an object via a form it uses the model objects and not the model manager and thus you'd need to override the `save` of your proxy model. If I modify your `Type2ProxyModel` to this it works:

```
class Type2ProxyModel(MyModel):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    objects = Type2Manager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.type = 'TYPE2'
        return super(Type2ProxyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: That is the solution. Thank you for the great explanation. Makes sense!